# Getting error setting up a git repo on a shared drive

Tags: windows, git

I would like to set up a git repository for several personal projects. I guess I'll do one repo per project; the projects are for different programs and libraries, not different parts of one program or system.

I'm on Windows 10 Pro, with a network drive I call Y. I'll put these repos in a directory cleverly named `git`. I found instructions to do this from the DOS command line:

```
Y:
cd \git\
git init --bare myrepo.git
```

Then, from the place where the code is I am going to want to put in the repository:

```
C:
cd \files\programming\workspaces\project1
git remote add origin y:\git\myrepo.git
```

When I execute the last line, I get the message:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I have tried it with slashes and backslashes; I have deleted the directory I created with the git command and done it over (in case I'd forgotten something), but still get the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put this in as a separate answer, in terms of setting up a second (and `--bare`) repository.  You've already done this on `Y:`.  You mention that this is a shared / network-accessible drive; that's sometimes OK, depending on how things work with lock files across shared drives.  There are OS-specific, file-system-specific, and network-specific details to be considered.  Let's just assume that they're OK, and/or that you and co-workers will be careful about who writes to the `Y:` drive.  Anyway, having done:

```
cd Y:\git\
git init --bare myrepo.git
```

you now have a second repository (made first, but the order of creation doesn't really matter).  Meanwhile you now do:

```
cd C:\files\programming\workspaces\project1
git init
```

which creates `.git` within `C:\files\programming\workspaces\project1`.  You can now add a *remote*, which is just a name for another Git repository in which you store the URL of the other Git repository:

```
git remote add origin file://Y:/git/myrepo.git
```

Now that there is a `.git` (repository) in `C:\files\programming\workspaces\project1`, this `git remote add` should work.  The name `origin` is simply conventional: you can use any name you like, but `origin` is the one that `git clone` creates when you use `git clone` to make the local (`C:` area) repository.

Git itself does not mind if the URL has backslashes, but some other software might, so it's probably wisest to stick with the normal slashes here.

You're now ready to have your local repository—the one in `C:\files\programming\workspaces\project1\.git`—call up a second Git over at `file://Y:/...`.  But there's no point connecting either of these two repositories until at least one of them has some commits, because commits are the main currency of exchange between two Git repositories.  So, any time before or after the `git remote add`, you'll want to make at least one initial commit, which will cause the branch name `master` to spring into existence.

Once you have a commit, or some commits, you can run:

```
git push origin master
```

The `git push` command connects your Git—the repository you're in right now—to some other Git.  The name `origin` here is the name of the remote, as set up by `git clone` normally, but by your `git remote add` in this particular case.  The last argument, `master`, is what Git calls a *refspec*.

Refspecs are a bit complicated.  They have two parts, separated by a colon `:` character.  This particular refspec, `master`, is missing the colon.  For `git push`, what that means is: *use the same name on both sides*.  So this is really shorthand for:

```
git push origin master:master
```

The name on the left of the colon is usually a *branch name* in your repository.  The name on the right side of the colon is the corresponding branch name in *their* repository—the other Git.

Your Git will now invoke another Git, often over a network connection (`ssh://` or `git://` or `http://` or `https://` URLs).  In this case, your Git works with the second Git repository directly, but you can just think of it as spinning off a second Git command that acts as the receiver for the other repository (because it actually does that).

Your Git now offers commits to that other Git, by their hash IDs.  They inspect the hash ID and check in *their* database of commit-and-other-Git-objects to see if they have those hash IDs.  Your Git wants to know: *should I give you, other Git, this one?  Or do you already have it?*  At this point, their database is empty, so the answer is always *I don't have that one - gimme!*  Your Git now packages these up, compressing them for network transfer, and sends them over.  They install these commits in *their* database.

At the end of this process, your Git sends their Git a polite request of the form: *Please, if it's OK, set your `master` now to point to the same commit that my `master` points-to.*  If they accept—and here, they will—they now have *their* `master` pointing to the last commit in the chain of commits that ends with the commit that is in *your* repository, that *your* Git finds via *your* name `master`.

If this sounds complicated, it's because it is: you and they don't share *branch names* at all, unless you and they want to.  But you and they *do* share *commit objects* with their unique hash IDs.

Fetching (and cloning) is not quite symmetric, but I'm out of time now for this answer.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you put into this; I need to allocate some time to going over all of it in detail later, since it covers so much more than just what I asked and includes things I'll want to know later on. The biggest issue was the one you mentioned in the first sentence of the first answer -- that the local directory was not a git repository. I *think* I understand it better now.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `C:\files\programming\workspaces\project1` is not a Git repository.

It's true that `Y:\git\myrepo.git` *is* a Git repository (assuming the earlier `git init` worked).  But `C:\files\programming\workspaces\project1` is not.  You'll need to create a second Git repository there.<sup>1</sup>  You could `git clone` the empty repository over in `Y:\git\myrepo.git`, for instance (although cloning a totally empty repository has some weird side effects and is usually not the right way to start).

The way Git works in general is:

- You clone an entire existing repository: every commit, which saves every version of every file, is now copied into the `.git` directory here.

  Git is really all about these commits.  Each commit has a full and complete snapshot of every file, frozen into a special, read-only, Git-only format, along with some additional information such as who made the commit, when, and why.  These commits act as archives: every time someone ran `git commit`, Git archived *everything*.<sup>2</sup>  You now have a copy of *everything*, in this special achival format that only Git can use.

  Each commit has its own unique hash ID.  No two commits can ever share an ID.  For this reason, and the fact that every Git in the world has to give *every* commit a unique hash ID, these IDs have to be very big and ugly and random-looking.  All Gits everywhere *share* hash IDs for all their commits, so that they can share their commits *by* ID, later.  You can connect any two Gits to each other and they can obtain each other's commits just by using these hash IDs.

  Because these hash IDs are so big and ugly, humans can't get them right.  Fortunately we don't have to; we'll see this in a bit.
- Then—this is actually built in, as the last step of the `git clone` you just did—you have Git *select* some commit.  That selected commit becomes the *current commit*.

  You usually select the commit by selecting a *branch name*, in which case that name becomes the *current branch name* as well, i.e., these two actions are paired up: selecting branch `master` as the current branch chooses the last commit *in* that branch as the current commit.

  (There's an extra complication here when doing that initial `git clone`, again, but we'll skip it for now.)
- Git now *extracts* all the files from the chosen commit, into a work area.  In this work area, you have ordinary files that you can use with all the ordinary programs on your computer.  These are your files, to work with as you wish: they're not Git's copies at all.  Git just *extracted* everything from a commit, in order to make these copies available.

Once you have all the working copies of files stored in this work area, which we call a *working tree* or *work-tree*, you can work with them.  That's why it's your work-tree: because you can actually get some work done.

Having worked on a bunch of files, you might want to save a new saved-for-all-time archival snapshot.  You might think you could just run `git commit` and Git would save all your files.  Other version control systems work this way, but Git does not.  Git has, in a secret file,<sup>3</sup> saved away *all* the files that came out of the current commit.  Those files are in the special Git-only frozen format, but unlike the copies of the files that are in commits, they're not actually *frozen*.  You can *replace* them, or remove some file(s) entirely, or put new ones in.

Git calls this special extra area the *index*, or the *staging area*, or sometimes—rarely these days—the *cache*.  These three names for this one thing reflect its central and multiple roles in Git, or perhaps there are three names because the original name, "index", is just so terrible. :-)  But either way, you need to know about the index.

Essentially—and leaving out some of its other roles—what the index is and does is represent the *next* commit you will make.  That is, it contains, in a special Git-specific format, some information about your current work-tree, but more importantly, a *copy of each file that will go into the next commit.*<sup>4</sup>

Having updated your work-tree files, you need to copy those files back into Git's index, which you do with `git add`:

```
git add file1 folder/file2
```

for instance.<sup>5</sup>  This *copies* these two files from your work-tree into the index, turning the copies into the special Git-only format, ready to go into the next commit.  In other words, these files are now *staged for commit*, hence the other name of the index, "staging area".  They're not actually *committed* yet but they are *ready to go*.  (They were ready to go before, too, but before, they matched the current commit's copy!)

At this point, running `git commit` makes a new commit from whatever files are in the index *right now*.  This new commit gets your name and email address as both author and committer, and "now"—the current date-and-time reported by your OS—as the time-stamps.  You should supply a log message giving the *reason* you made the commit: a summary of *why* you are doing whatever you are doing.<sup>6</sup>

The `git commit` command packages up all of this information—who, when, why, and so on—along with the raw hash ID of the *current* commit, and makes a new commit out of this plus the snapshot it makes using the files that are already in the right format in Git's index.  Now that the new commit is made, it *becomes* the *current* commit.  Now things are back to the way they were when you ran `git checkout`: the index and the current commit both contain the same set of files, in the frozen archive format, ready to go into a new commit.

Note that *no existing commit changes* during all of this.  In fact, no existing Git commit *can* ever change.  All commits are frozen for all time, read-only.  They continue to exist as long as you and Git can *find* them—usually forever, but you can arrange to "lose" one, if you've made one that you don't like.

The way Git *finds* commits is important, and a little tricky.  Once you get the hang of it, though, it's actually really simple.

---

<sup>1</sup>This may actually be the only repository you need: it's not clear why you wanted an empty and bare one in `Y:\git\myrepo.git` in the first place.

<sup>2</sup>More precisely, Git archived everything it was told to archive, as we'll see in a moment.

<sup>3</sup>It isn't really *secret* at all, but you can't *see* it very well: it's hidden in a specially-formatted file in `.git` named `index` (and maybe other places too, but they all start from the index file; the index file contains records, and some of them might list more files).

<sup>4</sup>Technically, what's in the index, in these *cache entries*, is the file's path-name, mode, and an internal Git *blob hash ID*.  There's also a *staging slot number* which is really only used for merging.  The hash ID means that rather than holding an actual copy of each file, the index just holds the record of the Git-formatted blob object.  But unless you start using `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index` directly, you don't really need to know about this: you can just think of the index as holding a copy of each file.

<sup>5</sup>You can use either forward slash like this, or backslash; both work.  I don't use Windows, and always use forward slash, and the few times I have been forced to use Windows briefly, I always name my files there with forward slashes.  (This mostly works, except for a few commands that insist on thinking they're switch options.  When dealing with Git and its ecosystem, backslash tends to confuse some other programs: `\b`, for instance, may represent a backspace, and `\t` a tab, so an attempt to name a file `.\buttons\toggle` can misfire and you end up with a file named `.^Huttons^Toggle` or something.)

<sup>6</sup>Git can easily show *what* you did, later, but Git has no idea that this was, e.g., to fix bug#12345 or issue#97 or whatever it might be, much less how the bug or issue could be described.  This log message is your opportunity to explain things like what the bug is, where to find it in the bug reporting system, what you discovered during investigation of the bug, and anything else that might be helpful to you, or someone else, looking at this commit later.

---

#### Branch names let Git find commits for you

A branch name like `master`, in Git, really just holds *one* hash ID.

That's all it needs to do.  We mentioned before that whenever you have Git make a *new* commit, the new commit saves the raw hash ID of the *current* commit.

Suppose you have an existing Git repository with just one commit in it.  This one commit has some big ugly hash ID, but we'll just call it `A` for short:

```
A
```

There's only the one commit in the repository.  That one commit has however many files, but it's just one commit.  It's easy to find: it's *the* commit.  Let's add a second commit now, by having this commit checked out via the name `master`—we'll put the name in, in just a moment.

We modify some work-tree files, `git add` them, and run `git commit` and give it a reason for the commit to put in the log message.  Git builds a new commit out of all of the files in the index, plus the usual metadata, including the hash ID of commit `A`.  Let's call the new commit `B`, and draw it now:

```
A <-B
```

`B` contains the old commit's hash ID.  We say that `B` *points to* `A`.

Git writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the *name* `master`, so let's draw the name `master` pointing to `B` now:

```
A--B   <-- master
```

I've already gotten lazy here (on purpose): it's `B` that points to `A`, not vice versa.  But the arrow coming out of `B` cannot change, because no part of any commit can change.  It's the arrow coming out of `master` that changes.  We call commit `A` the parent of `B`, and `B` a child of `A`.

The current branch is now `master` and the current commit is `B`.  Let's make a new commit in the usual way:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

New commit `C` points back to `B`, which points back to `A`.  So `B` may be a child of `A`, but it's also the parent of `C`.

(Where does `A` point?  The answer is: nowhere.  Commit `A` is a little bit special.  Being the *very first* commit, it can't point back to any earlier commit.  So it just doesn't.  Creating the first commit in a repository is a bit of a special act; it's what creates the *branch name*, too!  The name `master` is not allowed to exist until some commit exists, so creating commit `A` creates everything.)

(I keep saying *a child*, not *the child*.  That's because we can go back and add more children later.  Commits, once made, are frozen for all time, so the children know exactly who their parents are, but parents can acquire *new* children, someday, in the future.  When a new commit is made, it never has any children *yet*.  So parents never know who their children are.  That's why Git works backwards!)

Note how all we need is for Git to hold the raw (and random-looking) hash ID of the *last* commit in the name `master`.  We can remember the name `master`, and Git remembers the hash ID for us.  Adding a new commit consists of:

- making sure the current *branch name* is `master` (`git checkout master` if needed)
- so that the current *commit* is `C`
- so that Git's *index* is full of the right copies of files, and our *work-tree* has the files we want
- so that we can change work-tree files in place using all of the normal computer tools
- so that we can `git add` the updated files to make Git copy them back into the index
- so that we can `git commit` to make a new commit `D`

which will change our picture to read:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

All of these new commits go into our *repository*.  The repository itself is mainly just two big databases:

- the commits, and other internal Git objects, addressed by hash IDs;
- and a smaller *name-to-hash-ID* table, that says things like *branch name `master` means commit `a123456...`* or whatever.

The entire repository is in the `.git` directory / folder, underneath the top level of our work-tree.  The branch name(s) find the *last* commits, and those commits find earlier commits.  Git simply walks backwards, from last commit back to first one, one commit at a time.  Git knows that it has run out of commits to walk backwards through when it reaches a *root* commit like commit `A`, that has no parent.

There is a lot more to it than this, starting with the fact that you can add more branch names:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, dev
```

for instance, and move branch names around, and so on—and we haven't even touched on the idea of connecting *this* Git repository, in `C:\files\programming\workspaces\project1`, to another Git repository in `Y:\git\myrepo.git` or on another machine or whatever yet.  That's where things get complicated.  That's what `git remote` is for: a *remote* is a name you use in *your* Git to remember the URL for some *other* Git repository.

If you don't need to use remotes yet, don't do that; this is plenty to start with.

Comment: As I said, I want the repository on a *remote* drive, not on the same disk with the source. At the end you say "we haven't even touched on the idea of connecting **this** Git repository ... to another Git repository ... That's where things get complicated". I wanted to have the repository on the shared disk, clone it to the C drive, and then have 'push' commands put new commits on the shared drive. I don't think of 'clone' as creating a new repo, though I understand it makes a copy of the repo. Do I have that right? Is it possible to put the repo on the shared drive, and clone it it to C:?

Comment: I said "**remote**" drive, I meant **shared** drive.

Comment: It's never a good idea to put *your* repository on a *shared* drive (for various Git-specific reasons). You can have a shared repository, which you can do with a shared drive or just with ssh or other network access; that's the one you'll access as a Git "remote" (second repository stored elsewhere), and that's the one you'll set up as a bare repository, with `git init --bare`.